# Alternative to Worksheet_Activate

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet with data that links to a pivottable on another tab.  The data updates with slicers on the worksheet.  I also have code which hides/unhides blank rows in my data when the worksheet is activated.  However, I'd like the code to work when the users changes the slicer selections - I don't want them to have to leave the worksheet and then come back for the rows to hide.  Any suggestions?

```
    Option Explicit
 Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
 Dim r As Range, c As Range
 Set r = Range("a16:a65,a68:a118,a121:a171,a174:a224")
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each c In r.Rows
 If Len(c.Cells(1).Text) + Len(c.Cells(2).Text) = 0 Then
     c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
 Else
     c.EntireRow.Hidden = False
 End If
 Next c
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 End Sub
```

Comment: `Worksheet_selectionChange`?

Answer (score 0):

How about PivotTableUpdate event? This will have the code run every time the pivot table is updated, which would include when a slicer changes the filtering.

See [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.sheetpivottableaftervaluechange.aspx) for more information on this event.

Answer (score 0):

since slicers cause data updating you could use `Worksheet_Calculate` or `Workbook_SheetCalculate`

BTW I'd suggest the following coding style

```
For Each c In r
    c.EntireRow.Hidden = Len(c.Cells(1).Text) + Len(c.Cells(2).Text)
Next c
```